# SOAP web services NPE on redeployment Tomcat 6

Tags: soap, nullpointerexception, cxf, tomcat6

I'm using Tomcat 6 and I have a web application that uses a SOAP web service. I generated the client classes to use using cxf-codegen-plugin in maven, my dependencies are :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Everything works until I redeploy my war on tomcat (or even doing a simple touch on it: no code modification at all). Using the same url to access my page that makes the SOAP service call I have this weird NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ctc.wstx.util.SymbolTable.findSymbol(SymbolTable.java:385)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.parseLocalName(StreamScanner.java:1831)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleNsAttrs(BasicStreamReader.java:2997)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2941)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleRootElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2078)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2058)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1117)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.next(XMLStreamReaderFilter.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextElementContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.hasWSDLDefinitions(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:209)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:254)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:217)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:165)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:93)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
at some.package.flightinfo.model.flightstatsv2.soap.AirportsV1SoapService.<init>(AirportsV1SoapService.java:48)
at some.package.flightinfo.adapter.FlightStatsV2ContentAdapter.getAirportsByGPSCoordinate(FlightStatsV2ContentAdapter.java:107)
```

The only way I can get my web application working again is to restart tomcat which is no option at all.

I am totally clueless on what's going on, has anyone ever experienced this problem before?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are missing the cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws dependency.  Thus, you are ending up using the JAX-WS reference impl built into the JDK, not CXF. If you add the CXF dependencies, does that fix it?   Could be a bug in the RI or something.

Comment: Nope that doesn't solved it unfortunately :( Thanks anyway :)